# Why does my NamedEntityAnnotator for date mentions differ from CoreNLP demo's output?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

The date detected from my following program gets split into two separate mentions whereas the detected date in the NER output of [CoreNLP demo](http://corenlp.run/) is single as it should be. What should I edit in my program to correct this.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, entitymentions");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

String text =  "This software was released on Februrary 5, 2015.";
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(document);
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
      List<CoreMap> mentions = sentence.get(MentionsAnnotation.class);
      if (mentions != null) {
              for (CoreMap mention : mentions) {
                     System.out.println("== Token=" + mention.get(TextAnnotation.class));
                     System.out.println("NER=" + mention.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class));
                     System.out.println("Normalized NER=" + mention.get(NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class));
              }
       }
}
```

Output from this program:

```
== Token=Februrary 5,
NER=DATE
Normalized NER=****0205
== Token=2015
NER=DATE
Normalized NER=2015
```

Output from CoreNLP online demo:
[image]

Comment: What version of CoreNLP are you using? The online demo tracks the Git HEAD of the project fairly closely; there's a chance the difference in output is just a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Mine is v3.6.0 from [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/#download).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the online demo is showing any sequence of consecutive tokens with the same NER tag as belonging to the same unit.  Consider this sentence:

```
The event happened on February 5th January 9th.
```

This example yields "February 5th January 9th" as a single DATE in the online demo.

Yet it recognizes "February 5th" and "January 9th" as separate entity mentions.

Your sample code is looking at mentions, not NER chunks.  Mentions are not being shown by the online demo.

That being said, I am not sure why SUTime is not joining February 5th and 2015 together in your example.  Thanks for bringing this up, I will look into improving the module to fix this issue in future releases.

Comment: Turns out that I have misspelt 'February' as 'Februrary'. Fixed that and the entire date gets detected as a single mention, as expected. The misspelt month (+day) was still tagged as a DATE earlier and so I didn't suspect a typo. But good to know that the demo is doing chunking and not mentions detection.